# Is this matrix positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The matrix is:

\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_{i1}^2&...& \sum_{i=1}^{m} a_{i1}a_{in}\\ 
 \sum_{i=1}^{m} a_{i2}a_{i1}&...&\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_{i2}a_{in} \\ 
 ...& ...&...\\
\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_{in}a_{i1}&...&\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_{in}^2
\end{pmatrix}

which satisfies

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & ... & a_{1n}\\ 
 a_{21}& a_{22} &  ...& a_{2n}\\ 
 ...& ... &  ...& ...\\ 
  a_{m1}&  a_{m2} &  ... & a_{mn}
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with $m\geq n$ and the rank of $A$ is equal to $n$.

Is this matrix positive definite? And why?
Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Take a good look at your matrix, which I'll call $C$. Can you realise it as $BA$ for $B$ a certain matrix readily defined in terms of $A$? What would this then imply for the sign of $\langle \xi,C\xi \rangle = \langle \xi, BA \xi \rangle = \langle B^T \xi, A \xi \rangle$ for $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$? And then, what is $\operatorname{rank}(C) = \operatorname{rank}(BA)$ in terms of $\operatorname{rank}(A)$?

Comment: What's "sign"? What's your conclusion?

Comment: @Ian, sign as in "the sign of $3$ is positive; the sign of $-1.1$ is negative..."